# Meaning of "needle sure revs in the red" from "Rest"

Tags: song-lyrics, wordplay, alanis-morissette

From Alanis Morissette's song ["Rest"](https://genius.com/Alanis-morissette-rest-lyrics):

> All these relief-givers
> The needle sure revs in the red

Alanis is known for tinkering with structure and meaning. What does this sentence mean? My interpretation: is "Any painkiller or self-help advice is much less effective than injecting a substance", with "rev" as in providing a quick-fix and "red" as both blood and traffic light; a wordplay on running a red light.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs on ELL.

Comment: Why? Does not seem basic language learning to me (?)

Comment: I think Chenmunka suspects that you've missed that "revs in the red" is a common idiom meaning that the needle on a rev-counter (tachometer) is pointing at the red part of the gauge. If you know this and are looking for further metaphorical meanings, you should mention this in the question.

Comment: Exactly, that's why I associated the speedometer with bloodstream.

Answer (score 2):

"The needle sure revs in the red" is almost certainly an allusion to an engine RPM counter. It has a needle, it counts "revs", and it has a red zone - the area where the engine is in danger of being destroyed.

The likely interpretation is that the "relief givers" put the person in the zone where they are in danger of being destroyed.